# jQuery function to fade an image on window.scroll event not working

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, delay, fadeto

This should be really simple but I just can't figure out why it isn't working.

If the scroll top is within a certain region, then fade out an image. This works if scrolling with the mouse or using the keyboard arrow keys. But when you use the mouse to drag the scroll bar the function is called - I can see this in the log - but the jQuery fadeTo doesn't work immediately. If I stop scrolling, after about 5 seconds then the image fades.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();

    if(scrollYpos > 100 && scrollYpos < 200){               
        fade_out_img();
    }
    else{
        fade_in_img();
    }
});

function fade_out_img(){
    $("#image").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
}
function fade_in_img(){
    $("#image").fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[**`Working jsFiddle Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/wYUEj/)

You missed `stop()` method for your `fade_in_img` function.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: red;
}

#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**JavaScript** (written by jQuery)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();

        // for debugging
        $('<div>').text(scrollYpos).prependTo('#scroll');

        if(scrollYpos > 100 && scrollYpos < 200){               
            fade_out_img();
        }
        else{
            fade_in_img();
        }
    });

    function fade_out_img(){
        $("#image").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.1);
    }

    function fade_in_img(){
        $("#image").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/wYUEj/).